# How can a JavaScript class instance clear timers when it is dereferenced?

Tags: javascript, class, timer, garbage-collection

I have a situation like this:

```js
class Thing {
  constructor() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => console.log('Hi'), 1000);
  }
}

let a = new Thing();
// ... various stuff happens which takes less than 1s ...
a = undefined;
```

The problem is, the `a` instance of `Thing` continues to trigger the timer closure *after* `a` has been set to `undefined`:

> Hi
> Hi
> Hi
> Hi
> Hi

Now I could have the parent scope call a method to tell the instance to stop the timer, but the parent doesn't actually know a timer is being used - it's an internal implementation detail of `Thing`.

How can `Thing` know it's been dereferenced so it can clean up and allow itself to be GCed?

Comment: Your parent *should* now that there's an active process associated to `Thing`. What that process is might be an implementation detail, but starting and stopping it should be explicit. Avoid side effects in the constructor.

Comment: While I was incorrect that there's *no* way to do this, IMO you'd be better off with an explicit contract. GC is non-deterministic.

Comment: Notice that the `Thing` instance can and will be garbage-collected even when the interval is still running. Only if the `setInterval` callback had a reference to the instance (say, logging `this.something` instead of `'Hi'`), it would not be eligible for GC. And notice that if this is actually the case, a `FinalizationRegistry` won't help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`FinalizationRegistry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry):

```js
class Thing {
  constructor() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => console.log('Hi'), 1000);
  }
}

let a = new Thing();

const registry = new FinalizationRegistry(timer => {
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log('Cleared');
});

registry.register(a, a.timer);

a = undefined;
```

Note that it might take some time before the object is garbage collected. In my tests of the above code, the interval ran about 5-20 times before being eventually cleared.

Comment: I had no idea this existed.

Comment: @DaveNewton Same, until 5 minutes ago :)

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: This is not a good idea. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry#notes_on_cleanup_callbacks